# Complex XSLT String Split?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How can i split this string in XSLT

```
cast one : 'T','0','1','2'

cast two: 'T','0','1' 

case three: 'T','0'

i tried substring but the result is wrong 

substring-before(substring-after(String,','),',')
```

i want the result to be 0 after split

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your string values are. Assuming that for those three example values, the strings include the `'` single quotes, but you don't want the returned value to include the quote, and only be `0`?

Comment: You have used the tags for XSLT 2 and 3 so based on that you have the `tokenize` function, the `xsl:analyze-string` element and the `analyze-string` function. It is not clear, as already commented by Mads, what kind of string values you have and in which form, the syntax `'T','0','1','2'` is more the XPath syntax of a sequence of four single letter strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **XSLT 1.0**, you could apply additional `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` for the `'` character:

```
substring-before(substring-after(substring-after("'T','0'", ','), "'"), "'")
```

For **XSLT 2.0** ***(and greater)***, there are additional options.

You could use the [`tokenize()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) function to split the string by `,`, and then select the second item, and then use [`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-translate) to translate the `'` character into nothing:

```
translate(tokenize("'T','0','1','2'", ',')[2], "'", "")
```

or instead of `translate()`, you could use [`replace()`](http://w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) with a regex capture group and then select the value inside of the single quotes:

```
replace(tokenize("'T','0','1','2'", ',')[2], "'(.*)'", "$1")
```

Comment: i dont have tokenize so i cant use this way

Comment: then you likely are XSLT 1.0. You should update the tags on the question to reflect that.

Comment: ok thanks i update it now

Comment: do you know any solution that can help me in XSLT 1.0

Comment: Thanks Mads Hansen